# Issue connecting to AWS Postgres RDS from Heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, amazon-rds

I've been having trouble connecting to my aws db instance from my heroku app.

Here is what I have below:

I am using the node-postgres library to connect to the DB.

[In my VDC security group, I have the following inbound rule (This is the only inbound rule)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YaAM.png)

I have the following connection string
`` `postgres://${process.env.DBUSER}:${process.env.PASSWORD}@${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}/${process.env.DATABASE}?sslca=config/amazon-rds-ca-cert.pem` ``

When running locally I can connect fine and run my queries with no issues, but when deployed to heroku the following error is thrown when trying to connect.

```
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824590+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]: node:internal/process/promises:265
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824598+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]:             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824599+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]:             ^
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824600+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]: 
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824600+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.18.133.18:31702
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824600+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824601+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]:   errno: -110,
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824602+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]:   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824602+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]:   syscall: 'connect',
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824602+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]:   address: '52.18.133.18',
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824603+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]:   port: 31702
2022-02-10T20:35:03.824603+00:00 app[advanced-scheduler.2490]: }
```

I presume I am missing something at aws level but I've tried everything I've seen online and nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why on Earth are you connecting to port 31702?

Comment: By any chance are you .gitignore your .env file?
I ran into a similar issue and my fix was to remove .env from .gitignore
But this is a security issue.. so I am not sure what the workaround is for this.